# Drawing a realistic shrub/bush?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create a realistic shrub/bush. My goal is draw one similar to as shown in pic below:

[image]

Here is what i have done. I am using pen tool to draw a basic bush with green colour and then dark green shapes for lower region to show shade and light green shapes to show sunlight. But not able to make it look as realistic as shown in pic.

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using the pencil tool for this rather than pen tool - much easier to do lots of little rough details, which will make it look more like foliage and less like a blob. Pen tool is best for precision, and bushes aren't precise. [Hold alt before releasing with the pencil tool to make the path join up](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17414/).

Comment: add more shade and a sky, it would look more realistic I think.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are on the right track; you just need to work a little more on what you have. Making the outlines a little more jagged, and consider the lightsource should get you there. However, I would call this "stylised" not realistic.

Another option is to find a picture of a bush and then use Illustrators trace option. Here is a crude example, you would have to extract the tree from the background for best effect, and work more with the option in the `image trace.`

Image:

[image]

Illustrator Image trace with 16 colours:

[image]